# Use org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean as a connectionfactory

Tags: java, spring

I saw a bean definition as the below,

```
<bean id="connectionFactoryReceiver" class="com.myutils.messaging.TopicConnectionFactoryProxy">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
            <property name="jndiName" value="/us/UAT/eod:tcf"/>
            <property name="jndiTemplate">
                <ref local="jndiTemplate"/>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="login" value=""/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>
```

Also, the class TopicConnectionFactoryProxy has a setter as,

```
  public void setConnectionFactory(final QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
     if (connectionFactory == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("connection factory can't be null");
    }
    this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
   }
```

I know `org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean` can `getObject()` to return a connection factory object. However, can it be "directly" injected as a connection factory type?

Comment: FactoryBean is just a mechanism to create the factory for beans you need. Why you need to >  "directly" injected

Comment: The quoted bean definition is what I saw in a working system, and I just do not understand how it could work. It appears to me connectionFactoryReceiver expects to be injected with a connection factory type bean but instead with a JndiObjectFactoryBean.